# How to redirect a specific URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect http to https some specific url like login, signup

currently i am using bellow .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

using this all page redirect to https but i want to redirect only `example.com/login` and `example .com/signup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^login https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^signup https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```